# Saving the preferences in actionbar

Tags: android

I have a icon in actionbar to toggle between mute and unmute. Once the mute is clicked its excpected to be muted once the application is relaunched. Below is the code I am using, can anyone please help me to save the state of the volume.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem m){
    Log.v("ranjith","Onoptionsitemselected method entered");
    switch (m.getItemId()){

        case R.id.mutesound:{
            AudioManager c=(AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

            c.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,true);

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences if it's enough or use any of the other options available:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thanks...Sharedpreferences is an option, but I was wondering if there is some option in actionbar class for this.

Comment: @Ranjith As far as I know, the state has to be saved outside of the class to be able to read back when you restart the application.